# Can I use the @Value annotated into the a class annotated as @Entity?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, entity

I have a abstract class where I would do:

```
@Value("${dao.value:5}")
private Integer value;
```

The value return null, The abstract class is annotatedas @Configurable

This class is used in several class annotated as @Entity

This is the sping boot configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("package.dao")
@ComponentScan("package.server")
@EntityScan("package.model")
@Import(LoggerRegistryClientContext.class)
@EnableSpringConfigured
```

Comment: What `@Value` annotation? Not a JPA annotation, so clearly JPA providers couldn't care less if you did that

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer

Comment: Your model classes are not components, so the value won't be injected

Comment: @AlbertoAnderickJr What if you make that entity class annotated with Component annotation ? will it work ?

Comment: @SumanthVarada I don't think it's a good idea annotate entity classes as Component. It should work but would require more changes to your code to manipulate this data.